# PHP - password_verify() is always returning false

Tags: php, postgresql

I started an Android App with basic Register/Login functions. When I register, my app communicates with a PHP script (PHP 5.6.11) to send data to my database (PostgreSQL 9.4), which works fine.

The issue I'm having is on my Login function, when retrieving my information from the database and using password_verify(password, db_hash) to validate my login, which never seems to validate to true.

My sample code and database values are below:

```
<?php

   // connecting, selecting database
   $dbhost = "host=127.0.0.1";
   $dbport = "port=5432";
   $dbname = "dbname=test";
   $dbcredentials = "user=test_user password=test75";

   $connection = pg_connect("$dbhost $dbport $dbname $dbcredentials");

   /* get user inputs */
   $input_username = $_POST["username"];
   $safe_username = pg_escape_string($input_username);

   $input_password = $_POST["password"];
   $safe_password = pg_escape_string($input_password);

   /* check if user credentials are correct and return user information */
   $query = "SELECT username, password, email FROM \"user\" WHERE username='$safe_username';";
   $result = pg_query($connection, $query);

   /* get database credentials (result, row, value) */
   $result_array = pg_fetch_array($result, 0, PGSQL_NUM);

   $db_username = $result_array[0];
   $db_password = $result_array[1];
   $db_email = $result_array[2];

   if (password_verify($safe_password, $db_password))
   {
      $current .= "Password is valid!" . "\r\n";
   } 
   else 
   {
      $current .= "Invalid password." . "\r\n";
   }

  // dump the result object
   var_dump($result);
   var_dump($db_password);

   // close the connection
   pg_close($connection);

?>
```

I checked if my username and hash from the database were returning fine, and they are. The values are below:

> username = testing
>
> password = testing
>
> hashed password =
>   $2y$10$OIHovXZZ1aAHLL32JkLdeeMXZDcZ8TgcI8TFw5SVCQ9zBiqNc8pP6

To provide some additional information, my database table is configured like so:

```
CREATE TABLE "user"
(
  userid serial NOT NULL,
  username text NOT NULL,
  password text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (userid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Even after reading numerous identical posts regarding this exact issue I can't seem to resolve it.

Comment: You should output a JSON and do android JSON parsing codes..

Comment: This line ` $safe_password = pg_escape_string($input_password);` is probably the issue. Remove it and test against the $input_password

Comment: I'd suggest to use the pgcrypto extension that provide basic yet secure ways to encrypt and check passwords.

Comment: #1 - Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm really trying to encrypt/decrypt my password using PHP.

#2 -  I tried against the $input_password, it didn't work. I also tried taking off the "pg_escape_string" from when I submit my info to Register as well, it still didn't work.

#3 - I really would like to use this function, it's pretty straight-forward (even though I am having issues).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after looking for the solution I found this

`pg_fetch_array($sql_request)['password']` only can be invoked 1 time, after that it keeps returning false.